# ColdFusion URL Query and Usage

Tags: coldfusion

I'm looking to use "vanity" URLs to redirect to a login page, with a company logo on it.

The URL would be something like: `companyname.domain.com`

First, I need to query the requested URL to see if "companyname" exists, then either

1. serve the custom login page if it exists -OR-
2. show an error page if it doesn't.

The true destination will actually be something like `www.domain.com/folder/`. But again, I need to display the "vanity" URL throughout the whole application. Example:

```
    companyname.domain.com/clients/?id=somevariable&...
```

I know I can probably figure it out by trial and error over some period of time. But being a self-taught CF-er, I thought to gain some advice on the "right way" to go about this task.

Comment: There are several different elements here.  Which are you asking about? Do you want to extract the `companyname` from the domain name? Do you want to know how basic branching logic, and variable setting works (because that's basically what you're asking about). You can't really ask "How do I write my app?" you need to ask specific questions.

Comment: This is more commonly handled in the web server (IIS, apache or whatever). If you just wanted to redirect, thats easy enough with a straight CF solution, but the requirement that it display the vanity throughout the application is probably something you want to tackle in the web server.

Comment: This is fairly easy to do without this "vanity URL". A basic redirect as invertedSpear said above. But I've been asked to make this "masked" URL happen and wanted some input from someone who may have done something like this before. I'm NOT asking, "How do I write my app?". The application is already written. I'm looking for DIRECTION on something I've never attempted before. We're using IIS7.

Comment: Send *.domain.com to domain.com in IIS then use CGI.HTTP_HOST in CF to determine what was used, and whether it should show a login screen or an error.

Comment: Thanks ALL for the fast advice. I'll be testing the solution Peter suggested over the next few days, as soon as I get back on "this" project. As always, I appreciate the knowledge you guys take your time to provide.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up doing what I was looking for. Thanks for all the input.

First I added a DNS A record to the domain.com zone like this: * site-ip-address-here

```
<cfscript> 
    siteDomainName = cgi.http_host;
    if (ListLen(siteDomainName, '.') gt 2) {
        siteDomainName = ListFirst(siteDomainName,'.');
    }
</cfscript>

<cfif siteDomainName NEQ "www">

    <cfquery name="qUrl" datasource="#dsn#">
        SELECT id, pre
        FROM table
        WHERE pre = <cfqueryparam value="#siteDomainName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>

    <cfif qUrl.recordCount GT 0>
        <cflocation url="/folder/" addtoken="false">
    <cfelse>
        <cflocation url="http://www.domain.com/error.cfm" addtoken="false">
    </cfif>

</cfif>
```

If anyone has any comments on how it could've been done better, I'm always looking to learn something new.

Comment: You can simplify the ListGetAt to `ListFirst(siteDomainName,'.')`

Also, HTTP_HOST comes from the client, so you can't trust what it contains; [cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) is probably a good idea.

Comment: Oh, and you've got `LIKE` but no wildcards - either use `=` instead or add `%` to the end of the string to do a "starts with" test.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I appreciate the feedback.